# OpenGL Error COMPILE TIME

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl

I have written a simple code to test my Eclipse.
In the program I do not get any error but when I build the program I get the following error message :

[image: ERROR]

[image: PROGRAM]

Comment: The title is misleading. This looks like a link time error, not a compile time error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hack in GLUT, referred to as "ATEXIT_HACK". It is designed to workaround issues related to using different Visual C++ Runtime library linker options between the GLUT DLL and your application.

This hack should not be used with MinGW since it has its own C standard library, it is only necessary in Microsoft Visual C++. Unfortunately, the GLUT library tries to apply this hack anytime `_WIN32` is defined irrespective of the compiler used.

#### As such, you can add this preceding `#include <glut.h>`:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
# define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
#endif
```

Since you are using Eclipse, it should also be possible to add this pre-processor definition as a project option, but I could not tell you how to do that.